# How to get my methods to return the value I want?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

You can pull the repository of my full code from this link if you want: https://github.com/kenkuts/javaActivity.git

I am using inheritance, polymorphism and interfaces for this practice application. So far I have done the required task the assignment wants me to do. I don't think I did this part right where the assignment wants me to create a GradedActivity array named grades with four elements as a field and store a different class type for each GradedActivity array.

```
public class CourseGrades implements Analyzable {

    private GradedActivity labScore;
    private PassFailExam passFailScore;
    private Essay essayScore;
    private FinalExam finalScore;
    **private GradedActivity[] grades = {labScore, passFailScore, essayScore, finalScore};**

    public CourseGrades(GradedActivity lab, PassFailExam score, Essay essay, FinalExam finalExam){

        setLab(lab);
        setPassFailExam(score);
        setEssay(essay);
        setFinalExam(finalExam);

    }
```

The assignment also wants me to create 3 methods from an interface and write and call it in the main class. I know I messed up in the array part of the problem because my getAverage() method is not working and also my other two getLowest() and getHighest().

```
       public GradedActivity getHighest(){
       GradedActivity highest = new GradedActivity();

       for(int x = 0; x < grades.length; x++){

           if(grades[x].getScore() >= grades[x+1].getScore()){
             highest.setScore(grades[x].getScore());
           }
           else{
             highest.setScore(grades[x+1].getScore());
           }
        }
       return new GradedActivity(highest.getScore());
   }

   public GradedActivity getLowest(){
       GradedActivity lowest = new GradedActivity();

       for(int x = 0; x < grades.length; x++){

           if(grades[x].getScore() <= grades[x+1].getScore()){
             lowest.setScore(grades[x].getScore());
           }
           else{
             lowest.setScore(grades[x+1].getScore());
           }
        }
       return new GradedActivity(lowest.getScore());
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into streams for you getHighest and getLowest functions? You could just use a stream to do that in one line. 

`return new GradedActivity(Arrays.stream(grades.getScore()).max(Integer::compare).get()));` for max and `return new GradedActivity(Arrays.stream(grades.getScore()).min(Integer::compare).get()));` for min (code not tested)

Comment: Also, I cannot see the average function, but try `return Arrays.stream(grades.getScore()).average()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy Cow after googling and modifying some things I figured out the problems to my questions. For the GradedActivity array all I had to do was assign each array by each type of class object, which is shown:

```
public class CourseGrades implements Analyzable {

    private GradedActivity[] grades = new GradedActivity[4];

    public CourseGrades(GradedActivity lab, PassFailExam score, Essay essay, FinalExam finalExam){

        setLab(lab);
        setPassFailExam(score);
        setEssay(essay);
        setFinalExam(finalExam);

    }

    public void setLab(GradedActivity g){
        this.grades[0] = g;
    }
    public void setPassFailExam(PassFailExam g){
        this.grades[1] = g;
    }
    public void setEssay(Essay g){
        this.grades[2] = g;
    }
    public void setFinalExam(FinalExam g){
        this.grades[3] = g;
    }
```

What I did was instead of setting the GradedActivity arrays value into the object type I had different object references that were given their own object type. Thus:

```
private GradedActivity labScore;
private PassFailExam passFailScore;
private Essay essayScore;
private FinalExam finalScore;
```

After fixing this issue my getAverage() method started working.

```
        public double getAverage(){
        double average;
        double accum = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < grades.length; x++){

            accum += grades[x].getScore();

        }
        average = accum/grades.length;
        return average;
    }
```

Next was to fix my getLowest() and getHighest() methods. My first mistake was that I had an array that went out of bounds which is `grades[x+1].getScore();`. After fixing this I decided that the only way to pass the get lowest and highest grades was to declare an empty GradedActivity object then call the methods then after return the methods with class reference and put a .getScore() method in a `System.out.println();` hence from the main method:

```
    System.out.println("The average score is " + grade.getAverage());
    GradedActivity lowest = grade.getLowest();
    System.out.println("The lowest score is " + lowest.getScore());
    GradedActivity highest = grade.getHighest();
    System.out.println("The highest score is " + highest.getScore());
```

Damn thank you all for bearing with me.